# Soma de campos preenchidos dentro do próprio SELECT

Tags: mysql, query, select

tenho uma consulta SQL no seguinte formato:

```
SELECT XXXX AS duracao, 
    calcula_horas_manutencao({data_inicio_f}, {data_final}, contrato.id) as horas_manutencao,
    calcula_horas_sistema({data_inicio_f},{data_final}, contrato.id) as horas_sistema, [...]
```

Quero que o resultado da `duracao` seja a soma do `horas_manutencao` e do `horas_sistema`. Seria possível eu somar os dois sem ter que repetir a chamada das funções?

Query Completa:

```
SELECT SUM(X.horas_manutencao + X.horas_sistema) AS duracao, meses meses, horas_manutencao horas_manutencao, horas_sistema horas_sistema,
Limite_horas Limite_horas, Nome Nome, 
cliente_id cliente_id, Valor Valor, valor_real valor_real, diferenca diferenca
FROM (
    SELECT contrato.id AS contrato,
           calcula_meses_atendimentos({data_inicio_f} , {data_final}) AS meses,
           calcula_horas_manutencao ({data_inicio_f},{data_final},contrato.id) AS horas_manutencao,
           calcula_horas_sistema({data_inicio_f},{data_final} ,contrato.id) AS horas_sistema,
           sec_to_time(time_to_sec(contrato.limite_horas) * calcula_meses_atendimentos({data_inicio_f} , {data_final})) AS Limite_horas,
           cliente.nome Nome,
           cliente.id cliente_id,
           format_money(contrato.valor) Valor,
           calcula_valor_real(contrato.id) AS valor_real,
           (calcula_valor_real(contrato.id) - contrato.valor) AS diferenca
    FROM sis_contratos contrato
    LEFT JOIN sis_atendimentos atendimento ON contrato.id = atendimento.contrato
    LEFT JOIN sis_clientes cliente ON contrato.cliente = cliente.id
    LEFT JOIN sis_modulos modulos ON contrato.id = modulos.id
    WHERE contrato.id <>24
      AND contrato.status='Ativo Mensal' [ AND atendimento.data_inicio BETWEEN {data_inicio_f} AND {data_final} ]
    GROUP BY contrato.id
    ORDER BY cliente.id,
         cliente.nome,
         atendimento.data_inicio DESC
) 
AS X
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes fazer um um `SUBSELECT` da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT SUM(X.horas_manutencao + X.horas_sistema) AS duracao FROM (
    SELECT calcula_horas_manutencao({data_inicio_f}, {data_final}, contrato.id) as horas_manutencao,
    calcula_horas_sistema({data_inicio_f},{data_final}, contrato.id) as horas_sistema, [...] 
) AS X
```

Comment: Supondo que o `[...]` é o resto da minha SQL ele teria que ficar fora do SUBSELECT né?  
Tentei fazer `SELECT SUM(X.horas_manutencao + X.horas_sistema) AS duracao FROM (
    SELECT calcula_horas_manutencao('2018-01-01', '2018-11-05', contrato.id) as horas_manutencao,
    calcula_horas_sistema('2018-01-01','2018-11-05', contrato.id) as horas_sistema
) AS X, contrato.id AS contrato, [...]`  e voltou erro de sintax apontando para a próxima linha depois desse codigo.

Comment: Não, tem que ficar dentro do subselect

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu precisava, só que eu tinha um while no resto da query, isso aí parece que limita à um registro né?

Comment: coloca a query inteira pra eu ver...

Comment: Coloquei a Query completa acima,  entre `{ }` é variável.

Comment: A onde que está o while que você citou?

Comment: Na vdd ele não está limitando a um registro, ele está somando tudo, se você quer mostrar mais registros, deve indicar quais colunas quer fora do subselect a no final usar um `group by`

Answer (score 0):

Deverá transformar os campos para segundo ou minutos, timetosec ou sectotime.

Depois fazer a soma e converter novamente para formato de hora,minuto,segundo.

Comment: Fiz assim para somar amigo `sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(XXXX)))`, porém meu problema maior é como somar as duas funções sem ter que executá-las novamente.

(Preciso dos valores das funções e também da soma das duas).